# Using moment.js in an Angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am trying to evaluate `moment()` inside the curly braces `{{}}` to display a date:

```
{{ moment().date(timeslot.start.value.month)
           .month(timeslot.start.value.dayOfMonth - 1)
           .format("MMMM Do")
}}
```

However, this is rendering no HTML. Both `month` and `dayOfMonth` are set, and moment.js is pulled correctly because if I try to `console.log()` some date like `moment().date(6).month(6).format("MMMM Do")` it returns `"July 6th"` as expected.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning the value to a $scope variable in your controller and then wrap it in curly brackets

In your controller:

```
$scope.time = moment().date(timeslot.start.value.month)
       .month(timeslot.start.value.dayOfMonth - 1)
       .format("MMMM Do")
```

In your html:

```
{{time}}
```

Basically, only things attached to either "this" or "$scope" can be accessed in the view through double curly brackets or ng-bind. You have to assign it to that controller's scope that goes with the view.

Placing the moment operation right into the curly brackets doesn't work too well as I don't think Angular can interpolate an external library and its methods like that, but it can do more simpler options as you've probably seen.

Comment: Well not this exactly, but this gave me an idea. I already have a `helpers` object with helper functions hooked to the root scope. I just added another function that returned `moment()`. Really clumsy because I can't use anything else than `moment()` (and chain methods), but it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

have you look at an angular wrapper like [angular-moment?](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) 
Going the route of the wrapper always saves some headaches in terms of jQuery and Javascript libraries.

Here is a [plunker example based on your code.](https://plnkr.co/edit/76r1kZqtSzQSx1vh9JDO?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <span>{{myDate| amUtc | amLocal | amDateFormat:'MMMM Do'}}</span>
</body>
```

In the app I assign myDate to the current date:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularMoment']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
});
```

Comment: @devonJS Thank you for your help! I am still struggling with the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Chain `moment` to the rootScope in app/app.run.js:

```
$rootScope.moment = $window.moment;
```